# Use DEC2BIN() in Excel create a list

Tags: excel, binary, type-conversion, decimal

*Edit: I actually wrote my cell formula backwards and am not spending the amount of time required to reverse it now. Forwards or backwards works in my situation.*

I have the need to create a list of "options" that is using a 32-bit decimal number to select the binary options.

Example: 511 is given, which corresponds to 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1111 1111

I want to see this as "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ".

I have this massive 10 page cell formula that does this* (see below for an excerpt), but it seems like there must be a simple way.

Any Suggestions?

Here are the first two terms in the excel formula I have:

> "=IF(LEFT(DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^3),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^2),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^1),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^0),256),8),1)
>   = "1", " 32", "")&IF(MID(DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^3),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^2),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^1),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(I6,256^0),256),8),2,1)
>   = "1", " 31", "")&..."

Comment: "I want to see this as "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 "." You want to see 511 as 123456789?

Comment: Your description is poor. According to the formula excerpt 511 would result in 987654321 (rightmost 9 bits set). 502 would be 9876532 (bit 1 and 4 not set). Not clear what this shall be for at all.

Comment: @Vityata yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood is that you are trying to make `511` to `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1111 1111`, putting spaces every 4 times. Most probably it is not this, but I had some relative fun writing it, thus this is what I got:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

   Debug.Print DEC2BIN2(511)
   Debug.Print DEC2BIN2(511) = "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1111 1111"   'True
   Debug.Print DEC2BIN2(502) = "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1111 0110"   'True

End Sub

Public Function DEC2BIN2(inputVal As Long) As String

    Dim result As String
    Dim cnt As Long

    result = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(inputVal)
    result = AddZeroes(8 * 4 - Len(result)) & result
    result = StrReverse(result)

    For cnt = 1 To 8
        result = Insert(result, " ", 4 * cnt + cnt)
    Next cnt

    DEC2BIN2 = Trim(StrReverse(result))

End Function
```

`AddZeroes()` returns a string with N-zeroes. `Insert()` is used to insert a space in a specific position:

```
Public Function AddZeroes(zeroes As Long) As String

    Dim cnt As Long        
    For cnt = 1 To zeroes
        AddZeroes = AddZeroes & "0"
    Next cnt

End Function

Function Insert(original As String, added As String, pos As Long) As String

    Insert = Mid(original, 1, pos - 1) _
                    & added _
                    & Mid(original, pos, Len(original) - pos + 1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following functions:

```
Public Function Encoder(r As Range) As String
    Dim s As String
    Encoder = ""
    s = BigBinary(r)
    For i = 1 To 36
        If Mid(s, 37 - i, 1) = "1" Then Encoder = i & " " & Encoder
    Next i
End Function


Public Function BigBinary(r As Range) As String
    Dim addy As String, s1 As String, s2 As String

    addy = r.Address(0, 0)
    s1 = "=DEC2BIN(INT(A1/2^27),9)&DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(A1,2^27)/2^18),9)&DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(A1,2^18)/2^9),9)&DEC2BIN(MOD(A1,2^9),9)"
    s1 = Replace(s1, "A1", addy)
    s = Evaluate(s1)
    BigBinary = s
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

```
Macros must be enabled for this to work!
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for! My approach attempting to use a single cell formula ended up too long, but this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could mask each bit E.g.

```
Function bitOrdRev(slong As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, x As Variant
    x = CDec(slong)
    For i = 0 To 32
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Bitand(x, (2 ^ i)) <> 0& Then bitOrdRev = bitOrdRev & (i + 1) & " "
    Next
    bitOrdRev = RTrim$(bitOrdRev)
End Function
```

This assumes an unsigned value, so allows all 32 bits to be set with no sign bit ( `bitOrdRev("4294967295")` is `1..32`)